# Python FileNotFoundError when reading a public json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, aws-lambda

I have a public viewable JSON file that is hosted on s3. I can access the file directly by clicking on the public url to the s3 object and view the JSON in my browser fine. Anyone on the internet can view the file easily.

Yet with the below code is ran in Python (using Lambda connected to an API trigger) I get `[Errno 2] No such file or directory:` as the `errorMessage`, and `FileNotFoundError` as the `errorType`.

```
def readLeetDictionary(self):
        jsonfile = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/url/to/public/facing/file/data.json'
        with open(jsonfile, 'r') as data_file:
            self.data = json.load(data_file)
```

What am I missing here? Since the file is a publicly viewable JSON file I would assume I wouldn't be forced to use `boto3` library and formally handshake to the file in order to read the file (with `object = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_names,Key=object_name)` for example) - would I?

Comment: [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) is a built-in function that opens local files, not remote http resources.

Comment: ah thanks @metatoaster

Comment: I agree with @metatoaster 's comment. You need to get your file in local fs first.

Answer (score 0):

The conde you need should be something like:

```
import urllib, json
def readLeetDictionary():
      jsonfile = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/url/to/public/facing/file/data.json'
      response = urllib.urlopen(jsonfile)
      data = json.loads(response.read())
      print data
```

Please feel free to ask further or explain if this does not suit you.